# Spring Security 3: Method Level Access Failure

Tags: spring-security

I have url-level security in placed, and also, method level.  But my method level security is bypassed once the user has been authenticated at the url-level!  I looked at this further and it seems that the following url-level security:

`intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"`

would override any of my method level security (like below code snippet).

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')")
public String supervisorRoleOnly() 
{ 
     return "success!!!" ;
}
```

I would think that this method would throw an access-denied error, but no, any ROLE_USER can access this method once they are already authenticated at the url-level.

I do have this in my `security-config.xml`:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" >
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this applies more to future readers, but when you set debug logging for Spring Security do you see something similar to following:

```
Looking for Pre/Post annotations for method 'supervisorRoleOnly' on target class 'yourClassName'
No expression annotations found
Adding security method [CacheKey[yourClassName; public yourReturnType yourClassName.supervisorRoleOnly()]] with attributes [ROLE_USER]
```

PreAuthorize is probably being ignored.